# List information for all versions of a Maven artifact

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-repository

I want to list all the versions of a Maven artifact along with their publish dates. Is there any `maven` command for this?

To do it programmatically, all I found till now is this maven repository link: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2. For example, the repository lists the version information for `org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync` [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-sync/). If there is no maven command, is this repository URL a reliable source for all Maven artifacts? Is there any other options?

Comment: What about https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-sync ?

Comment: The data is the same, so I guess the repository I asked about is accurate